# Bluetooth stopped connecting

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, blueman

I was using my wireless earbuds on Ubuntu (20.04) without any problems for a month, but yesterday they got disconnected abruptly and nothing won't connect to the bluetooth. In regular bluetooth settings I can't even toggle the connection slider

[image]

and blueman gets stuck on "connecting.."
[image]

I tried to remove all bluetooth related packages with

```
sudo apt-get autoremove blueman bluez-utils bluez bluetooth
```

But that didn't help. Is there any way to fix this or to completely reset bluetooth settings?